# React Native header bar

Tags: android, typescript, react-native, mobile

How can I configure the Android header bar background color similar to the ios with react native?

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `StatusBar` (https://reactnative.dev/docs/statusbar)

```
import { StatusBar } from 'react-native';
// ...
StatusBar.setBackgroundColor("#000000");
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use this**

```
<StatusBar backgroundColor="yellow" />
```

For more info read [this](https://reactnative.dev/docs/statusbar)

Answer (score 0):

Great Question!

You can use the react-native StatusBar tag :

**Just do this :**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Platform, StyleSheet, View, StatusBar } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';


class MyStatusbar extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.StatusBar}>
                <StatusBar translucent barStyle = "light-content" />
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    StatusBar: {
        height: Constants.statusBarHeight,
        backgroundColor: '#6a11cb'
    }
});

export default MyStatusbar;
```

and where you want the status bar use :

```
import MyStatusbar from './file-location'
```

and in the return(); :

```
<MyStatusbar />
```